# action for ajax.beginform throwing 404 from mvc app not from fiddler

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, action, ajax.beginform

I have the following and am getting a 404 on submit, but from fiddler I'm getting a 500 error about not having the antiforgerytoken.  Any thoughts what might be wrong?

ShareController.cs code

```
// creates the form
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShareVideoFormEmail(string vguid)
{
    var shareModel = GetShareVideoFormEmailModel(vguid);

    return PartialView("ShareVideoFormEmail", shareModel);
}
// handler function
[HttpPost]
[ValidateHoneyPot]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ProcessShareVideoFormEmail(ShareVideoEmailModel model)
{
    //do stuff
    return PartialView("Result");
}
```

ShareVideoFormEmail.cshtml

```
@model Gcc.GctWebsite.Areas.Forms.Models.Share.ShareVideoEmailModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProcessShareVideoFormEmail","share",null ,new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "shareVideoFormWithMyFriends",
    OnBegin = "onBeginShareEmail", @* show ajaxspinner *@
    OnComplete = "onCompleteShareEmail", @* hide ajaxspinner *@
    OnSuccess = "onSuccessShareEmail" @* hide ajaxspinner *@
}, new { id = "shareVideoEmailModelForm" }))
{
<div class="modal-header">
        <div class="modal-header-title">Share the video &quot;@ViewBag.VideoTitle&quot; with my friends</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id ="shareVideoFormWithMyFriends" class="share-form-email">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HoneyPot()
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UpdateTargetId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.OgMetaTitle)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.OgMetaDescription)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.OgMetaDefaultImage)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.OgMetaImage)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Brand)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.VGuid)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TripCode)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.EmailSubject)
<!-- big section of input fields for model properties -->
<div class="form-field">
    <span class="req-lbl">* = Required</span>
</div>
<div class="form-field form-submit">
    <input class="btn btn-main-theme btn-narrow btn-submit-form" value="Send Email" type="submit">
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-grey btn-reset cancel-share-Email" value="Cancel">
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.required-input').after("<span class=\"rqdfield\">*</span>");
    loadJqueryValidationManually("#shareVideoEmailModelForm");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why `ShareVideoFormEmail(string vguid)` is decorated with `[HttpPost]` attribute if the this Action only gets information and do not change the state of your site?

Comment: Are you missing the close curly bracket of `@using`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in my model in some of the data there were some html no-no's.  I had to htmlencode a couple properties before displaying the view, then it worked fine upon postback.
I discovered this by changing the input parameter of the action method to object and removing the honeypot and xsfr validation.  Then I got a nice 500 error explaining I had unsafe data.